# Disable select option with angular ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

following the angular documentation

[ng-options guidelines](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/docs/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

I write that part of code:

```
<select ng-model="model" ng-options="item.CODE as item.NAME disable when item.DISABLE for item in list" id="foo" name="foo" ng-change="change()">
```

but return me back this error:

> Syntax Error: Token 'disable' is an unexpected token at column 11 of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to wrong syntax. For disable with array there is only two syntax available.

1. label disable when disable for value in array
2. label disable when disable for value in array track by trackexpr

Try out following:

```
<select ng-model="model" ng-options="item.CODE disable when item.DISABLE for item in list" id="foo" name="foo" ng-change="change()">
```

Comment: Well, he is having an object data  source, i thing, not an array!

Comment: @VictorBenetatos the name(`list`) gave me hint it is the array.

Comment: Are you saying `item.one as item.two` cannot be used when using disable?

Comment: @ste2425 ummm, Yes it is as per the document.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya ahh didn't see the version of the docs, as mentioned this is perfectly valid syntax in newer version which confused me.

Comment: So you think the problem is that I'm using an array with that format:

[{CODE: "", NAME: "", DISABLE: true}, ..]

Comment: @Roberto Yes. or use this syntex `select as label disable when disable for (key, value) in object`

Comment: I try as you write in your first answer but still didn't work. Now I'm going to try with new syntax you write now.

Comment: @Roberto it works look at my plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1J9Xv6yB34ZfcUrSDrGv).

Comment: @Jenish yes but doing like that on the select appear the CODE string and not the NAME string

Comment: I need that the select show the tiem.NAME but to the MODEL go the item.CODE

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the angular.js version. This functionality was added in version 1.4.X and above.

Comment: Well, I think Whole ngOption directive was not there in earlier version.

Comment: I'm using version 1.4.4

Comment: when i change to https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js (v1.4.5) this version disable things  worked fro me earlier i had  v1.3.0